# Content of Textview is deleten when i execute the intent(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For example i have an app to make a shopping list.First activity shows the content of the list.Second one is to add items to the list and it has textviews and button.I used textviews to add items to the list.If you click any textview, related item is added to the shopping list.But you need to click the button to go without adding anything.And i am using an intent for this but if i click that button everything i added the list earlier is deleted.What is the problem and solution(s)?ty

Comment: Please add code here to review.

Answer (score 0):

Pls add code ..
however I think the problem can be solved if you need to pass all the data to the 2nd activity and rcv the intent...and when you set the onclick listener for the button in 2nd activity...all data need to be passed back with the intent and set on the list.

If you add the code it will help